# POST requests API using Python - status code 500

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, post, python-requests

I am writing a script in Python (3.7.4, Windows 10) for a POST request (REST API), the object is to retrieve data from another database and move it to another.

```
from os import getenv
import requests

# header includes login credentials and content type
header = {'access_key': "key", "access_token": getenv("token1"), 'content-type': 'application/json'}

# Body includes table names and other specified data to retrieve
body = {
# table names etc.
}

# Post request and printing of the post request text
post_r = requests.post(url = POST_url, data = body, headers = header)
post_text = post_r.text
print(post_text)
```

This throws me an HTTP Error status code 500. What should I change in my code for it to print the *post_text* correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution:

```
post_r = requests.post(url = POST_url, data = body, headers = header)
```

should be changed to

```
post_r = requests.post(url = POST_url, json = body, headers = header)
```

So, I just replaced **data** with **json** and the script printed me the *post_text* output just fine.

It did not help to change the **'content-type'** in **header** to **'application'**. It threw me status code 415 (*"HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format. The format problem might be due to the request's indicated Content-Type or Content-Encoding , or as a result of inspecting the data directly."*).

I still wonder why **data = body** is not acceptable in the post request row.

Comment: What version of `requests` are you using. I think that in the past, `data=` expected a string containing a json payload if you specify the header but `json=` accepted a dictionary instead (and also no longer required you to specify the header). But looking at the most current docs, it looks like `data=` also accepts dictionaries now...

Comment: My package version numbers are

requests==2.22.0 and 
requests-oauthlib==1.2.0.

I think it is a dictionary in my case but I am curious to find out more about the data = body not working, especially if the current docs say it might work.

Comment: A simple way to test it for you is to try `data=json.dumps(body)` and see if that works (Just make sure you still have the `'content-type': 'application/json'` in your header). If it does, then it is strings for `data=` dicts for `json=`.